# Error in function, the output must be 30 but not answering where is the problem?

Tags: python

Error in function, the output must be 30 but not answering where is the problem?

```
def sum(low, high):
    result
    for number in xrange(low, high):
        result = number
    return result
sum(4,8)
```

Comment: If you're doing a sum, you'll need to add numbers. Are you adding numbers anywhere in this function?

Comment: There are three problems:  (1) `result` appears by itself before the `for` loop.  Change it to `result = 0` (2) in the loop, you are assigning values to result without adding them to it.  Change it to `result += number` (3) If you want the range to be inclusive of `high`, as your expected output indicates, then you need to add 1 to it, i.e. `xrange(low, high + 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Update: changed to xrange, tested it on Python 2.7 and works.

---

What is your Python version? Range doesn't include last digit, that's why I increased it in 1.

```
def sum(low, high):
  result = 0
  for number in xrange(low, high+1):
      result += number
  return result

print(sum(4,8))   # 30
```

Comment: FYI, `xrange` in Python 2 and `range` in Python 3 are essentially equivalent.  `range` in Python 2 is equivalent to `list(range(...))` in Python 3, i.e., it returns a list.  Basically you always want to use `xrange` in Python 2, except when you actually need a list.